# The official npx documentation says, "all flags and options must be set prior to any positional arguments." What does this mean?

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

The [official npx documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npx#npx-vs-npm-exec) says,

> #### `npx` vs `npm exec`
>
> When run via the `npx` binary, all flags and options *must* be set
> prior to any positional arguments.  When run via `npm exec`, a
> double-hyphen `--` flag can be used to suppress npm's parsing of
> switches and options that should be sent to the executed command.

While it includes many examples of passing flags and options to `npm exec`, as far as I can tell, it doesn't explain anything beyond this for the `npx` command line.

*In this context*, what does it mean by, "positional arguments?" Please include examples of setting "options and flags" before positional arguments in a `npx` command.

Comment: _`npx something`_  "something" is a positional argument

Comment: @Phil If this is easy to answer, what things *aren't* positional arguments?

Comment: Options (`--option`) and flags (`-s`)

Comment: @Phil okay, thanks. Based on your comments, I assume `npm exec --inspect -- tap --bail test/foo.js` could be rewritten like this: `npx --inspect -- tap --bail test/foo.js`?

Comment: Does the [_"For example"_ section](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npx#npx-vs-npm-exec) not make it clear?

Comment: I think the idea is the `npx` example doesn't need the `--` because everything after `tap` is explicitly passed to the `tap` command. `npm exec` will greedily grab all flags and options for itself without `--`

Comment: @Phil no... why would it? There's no example showing how to use `npx` "prior to any positional arguments"

Comment: @Phil `I think the idea is the npx example doesn't need the -- because everything after tap is explicitly passed to the tap command.` Right, and [that's why I needed to modify their example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77568045/the-official-npx-documentation-says-all-flags-and-options-must-be-set-prior-to?noredirect=1#comment136747918_77568045) in an attempt to answer my own question: the official documentation does not include an example of doing this. I still don't know if the code in my comment is valid though. I'm just guessing.

Comment: You must have missed the _`npx --package=foo bar --bar-argument`_ example

Comment: The npm docs could indeed be more explicit probably: its example `npx foo@latest bar --package=@npmcli/foo` is to be understood as opposed to the synopsis `npx --package=<pkg>[@<version>] -- <cmd>` (i.e. `npx --package=@npmcli/foo foo@latest bar`), where placing the `--package` option before or after the `foo@latest bar` positional arguments gives a different behaviour of `npx`, whereas `npm exec` would use it in both cases.

Comment: @Phil indeed, I did. In my defense, the setup to that example is presented as unrelated: "Run a command other than the command whose name matches the package name by specifying a --package option"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, `npm exec` is greedy when it comes to options and switches (flags). It will assume any provided are for itself. This can be avoided by separating them with `--`.

`npx` on the other hand treats any options or flags provided *after* the positional argument (eg the command / binary / executable) as for the command.

Consider the structure of each of these commands

#### npm exec without separation

```sh
npm exec --inspect tap --bail test/foo.js
```

The command is `tap test/foo.js`. The options for `npm exec` are `--inspect` and `--bail` with the latter being ignored.

#### npm exec with separation

```sh
npm exec --inspect -- tap --bail test/foo.js
```

The command is `tap --bail test/foo.js`. The options for `npm exec` are `--inspect`.

#### npx

```sh
npx --inspect tap --bail test/foo.js
```

The command is `tap --bail test/foo.js`. The options for `npx` are `--inspect`. It did not grab `--bail` for itself because the option came after the positional argument `tap`.